model.summary() doesn't return proper output shape in keras sequential model
When model.summary() is called it returns all params as 0.
model= Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(int(total_words),100,input_length=int(max_sequence_len)-1))  
##total_words=4818 and max_sequence_len=14 manually verified
model.add(LSTM(150,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(int(total_words),activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

Here is the output


The TensorFlow/Keras API doesn't show the output shape or the number of parameters in model.summary() because, in some cases, it doesn't have enough information to infer the shape of the input data. This usually happens when the model's input shape is not explicitly defined or when dynamic shapes are used. There are two ways to resolve this:
1. Explicitly define the input shape:
You can provide the model with the input shape upfront by specifying it in the first layer, this will allow TensorFlow to properly infer the output shape and the number of parameters.
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(block_size,))) # input layer

or (another way to specify the input shape)
model.build(input_shape=(batch_size, block_size))

2. Provide a sample input:
Another way to resolve this is by passing a sample input to the model. You can do this by creating a dummy input array with the shape you expect the model to process. This allows TensorFlow to compute the shapes and parameters properly (the commented code)
input_example = tf.random.uniform((batch_size, block_size))
model_output = model(input_example)

print(f"input_example.shape: {input_example.shape}")
print(f"model_output.shape: {model_output.shape}\n")

The complete code:
vocab_size = 4818 # total_words

batch_size = 64
block_size = 14 # max_seq_len
n_embd = 16

model = Sequential()
# model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(block_size,))) # input layer
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, n_embd)) # token embeddings of shape (b, t, n_embd)
model.add(LSTM(units=150, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=100))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))

# input_example = tf.random.uniform((batch_size, block_size))
# model_output = model(input_example)

# print(f"input_example.shape: {input_example.shape}")
# print(f"model_output.shape: {model_output.shape}\n")

model.build(input_shape=(batch_size, block_size))
model.summary()

The result:

